# Hermitian matrix PD iff partitioned matrix of imaginary & real parts is PD?

Tags: linear-algebra

Claim:
Given $B + Ci = M = M^* \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n} \space$ with$\space B, C \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, M \succ 0 \space$ if and only if $\space
\begin{bmatrix}
    B & C \\
    C^T & B \\
\end{bmatrix}
\succ 0$.

According to a couple linear algebra texts, this is apparently true, but I can't find a proof anywhere.  I suspect it may involve Schur complements but I can't massage it into the right form.  Proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Schur complement. The statement is true merely because
$$
(u-iv)^T(B+iC)(u+iv)=(u^T,-v^T)\pmatrix{B&C\\ C^T&B}\pmatrix{u\\ -v}
$$
for any two real vectors $u,v\in\mathbb R^n$ when $B$ is symmetric and $C$ is skew-symmetric.